# How to convert Bufferedimage to indexed type and then extract the argb color palette

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage, indices, palette

I need to convert a BufferedImage to a BufferedImage indexed type to extract the indices of the colors data and the 256 color palette.
i think that i am doing right the conversion of a BufferedImage to indexed mode and then extracting the color indices with the next code:

```
BufferedImage paletteBufferedImage=new BufferedImage(textureInfoSubFile.getWidth(), textureInfoSubFile.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
paletteBufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(originalBufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

// puts the image pixeldata into the ByteBuffer
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) paletteBufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

My problem now is that i need to know the ARGB values of each color index( the palette) to put them into an array. i have been reading about ColorModel and ColorSpace but i don´t find some methods to do what i need.

Comment: testing my code i saw that the conversion misses the transparency and i need to conserve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solve it with this code:

```
public static BufferedImage rgbaToIndexedBufferedImage(BufferedImage sourceBufferedImage) {
    // With this constructor, we create an indexed buffered image with the same dimension and with a default 256 color model
    BufferedImage indexedImage = new BufferedImage(sourceBufferedImage.getWidth(), sourceBufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);


    ColorModel cm = indexedImage.getColorModel();
    IndexColorModel icm = (IndexColorModel) cm;

    int size = icm.getMapSize();

    byte[] reds = new byte[size];
    byte[] greens = new byte[size];
    byte[] blues = new byte[size];
    icm.getReds(reds);
    icm.getGreens(greens);
    icm.getBlues(blues);

    WritableRaster raster = indexedImage.getRaster();
    int pixel = raster.getSample(0, 0, 0);
    IndexColorModel icm2 = new IndexColorModel(8, size, reds, greens, blues, pixel);
    indexedImage = new BufferedImage(icm2, raster, sourceBufferedImage.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    indexedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceBufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
    return indexedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is good (except that you don't "put" any data into anything, you merely reference the data buffer's backing array, meaning changes in `pixels` will reflect to `paletteBufferedImage` and vice versa).

To get the ARGB values for the indices in `pixels`:

```
IndexColorModel indexedCM = (IndexColorModel) paletteBufferedImage.getColorModel(); // cast is safe for TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED
int[] palette = new int[indexedCM.getMapSize()]; // Allocate array
indexedCM.getRGBs(palette); // Copy palette to array (ARGB values)
```

For more information, see the [IndexColorModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html) class documentation.